# Analytic Number Theory Notation dillemma

Tags: analytic-number-theory

The following question is in regard to material sourced (and presumablty authored by) M.Ram Murty in the publication "Problems in Analytic Number Theory, Second Edition", page 18.

And I am starting to feel like the use of curly brackets is an inside joke amongst those further along the path than I am right now, but none the less I just woke up and I'm baffled by this first step, and really would like someone to explain this step in a generalized sense, from an axiomatic stance if possible.

The author declares the following to be very useful, for which it is indeed very useful for me at this point:

Suppose ${\{a_n}\}_{n=1 }^\infty$ is a sequence of complex numbers and $f(t)$ is a **continuously differentiable function** on $[1,x]$.

Set 
$$A(t)=\sum_{n \leq t}a_n$$
Then
$$\sum_{n \leq x}a_n f(n)=A(x)f(x)-\int _{x}^{1}A(t)f^{'}(t)dt$$
First we suppose $x$ to be a natural number, we write the left hand side as:
$$\sum_{n \leq x}a_n f(n)=\sum_{n \leq x}{\{A(n)-A(n-1)}\}f(n)=\sum_{n \leq x}A(n)f(n)-\sum_{n \leq x-1}A(n)f(n+1)$$

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: What is the purpose of using the curly brackets and what are any axiomatic declarations relevant to the algebra implied here

Comment: ?? Here the brackets are just parentheses and the summation formula follows from the elementary manipulations in your post. $\int_n^{n+1} A(t) f'(t)dt = A(n) (f(n+1)-f(n))$, $\int_1^{N+1} A(t) f'(t)dt =\sum_{n=1}^N\int_n^{n+1} A(t) f'(t)dt$ $=\sum_{n=1}^N\int_n^{n+1} A(n) f'(t)dt=\sum_{n=1}^N A(n) (f(n+1)-f(n))$

Comment: Then why did the author use differing symbols for these parentheses people don't just change things on such an elementary level notation wise for no reason what so ever come on

Comment: Ok your help is indeed very help and I can move forward from here, shall I delete or keep the question? Because if it doesn't have an significance I can just accept that as an answer and move forward in my book work

Comment: Maybe using $\{,[,($ is a matter of fonts they didn't have on typewritters

Comment: Ok true that's a very reasonable explanation I guess I can accept that as the answer too